# IBAction Method not calling in viewDidLoad Method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

In my app I want to call `IBAction` method in `viewDidLoad` method. I am calling `[self myContest:nil];` like this. When I click on `IBAction` Method it is working fine but initially launch the screen it is not working.

initially my screen like this,

[image]

and here is the IBAction Code,

```
-(IBAction)myContest:(id)sender
{
 value = 0;
 [tableViewContest reloadData];
 if(str.length > 0)
   {
     NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   }
}
```

What is the Problem? any help.

Comment: Define "not calling" exactly. If you put a `NSLog()` or a breakpoint on `myContest:`, do you see the call? How are you supposed to know it's working?

Comment: @Larme it is calling but not showing any thing.

Comment: What it is supposed to show?

Comment: @Larme see my above screen when initially loading the view controller.i want like this

Comment: Can you show what's the screen before your call in viewDidLoad() and then after you pushed the button?

Comment: Your tableview is not showing the right content when the button action is triggered from viewdidload ? If so make sure that necessary contents to populate have been there before calling table reloaddata method.

Comment: I agree with @Unni. It would be great to show exactly when it is called in `viewDidLoad:` and what you do.

Comment: your tableview data is coming to web-api.pls add some another code.

Comment: try this code - (void)viewDidLoad
{    value = 0; if(str.length > 0)
   {
     NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
   }[tableViewContest reloadData];}

Comment: it is my tableview data loading problem sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

`IBAction` is called for an action. To achieve your requirement, you can create a function with the code that you want to execute and than call this function from your `viewDidLoad()` method as well as from `IBAction()` method of the button.

```
void doTask() {
     value = 0;
     [tableViewContest reloadData];
     if(str.length > 0)
     {
         NSData* data = [str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
     }
}
```

Now call this function from where ever you want like:

```
-(IBAction)myContest:(id)sender {
    doTask():
}
```

or

```
- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
    doTask():
}
```

Comment: i will try and inform u.

Comment: What's the issue? Did you try debugging the issue?

Comment: How is this supposed to fix the author issue? You can call an IBAction from code.

Answer (score 0):

firstly if you want to call it in ViewDidLoad you have to change it because you cannot call an IbAction method to viewdidload directly

`-(IBAction)myContest:(id)sender`

to

`-(void) myContest`

then you will be able to call it in `viewDidLoad` method

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    [self myContest];

}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to fix the author issue? You can call an `IBAction` from code.

Answer (score -1):

One way is that just create a `IBOutlet` of that button

`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *btn`

and then fire click event of that button programmatically.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [btn sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to programmatically fake a touch event to a UIButton in your viewdidload

```
[buttonObj sendActionsForControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: You don't have to "fake a touch".